# spring security 4 using twitter bootstrap and apache tiles (able to login but not logout).HTTP ERROR 404

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security, tiles

I am using spring security 4 to secure an application. I am also using apache tiles for the view. I am able to login to the application but unable to logout. Can someone point out what is wrong with my code?

I get Below error message when performing logout.

> HTTP ERROR 404
>
> Problem accessing /logout. Reason:
>
> ```
> Not Found
> ```

if i disable csrf it logs out fine. But I want csrf enabled and my application should work

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>    
</web-app>
```

security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/users**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/users/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <form-login login-page="/login.html"/>
        <logout logout-url="/logout"/>

    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
            <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </user-service>
            </authentication-provider>
            </authentication-manager>

    </beans:beans>
```

Apache template classic.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles-extras" prefix="tilesx" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-  BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-    rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-    Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title><tiles:getAsString name="title"></tiles:getAsString></title>
</head>
<body>

<tilesx:useAttribute name="current"/>



    <div class="container">

    <!-- Static navbar -->
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
     <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<spring:url value="/"/>">JBA</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="${current == 'index' ? 'active':'' }"><a href='<spring:url value="/"/>'>Home</a></li>
          <li class="${current == 'users' ? 'active':'' }"> <a href='<spring:url value="/users.html"></spring:url>'>Users</a></li>
          <li class="${current == 'register' ? 'active':'' }""><a href='<spring:url value="/register.html"/>'>Register</a></li>
          <li class="${current == 'login' ? 'active':'' }""><a href='<spring:url value="/login.html"/>'>Login</a></li>
          <li ><a href='<spring:url value="/logout"/>'>Logout</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>

<tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/>

<br><br>

<center><tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"/></center>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

login.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>   

<style></style>



 <form class="form-signin" action='/login' method='POST'>
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="text" name='username'  class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" name='password'  class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="submit" type="submit">Sign in</button>
     <input type="hidden"  name="${_csrf.parameterName}"   value="${_csrf.token}"/>
  </form>
```

LoginController.java

```
package cz.laxi.org.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class LoginController {


@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login(){
    return "login";
}
}
```

LogoutCotroller.java

```
  @Controller
 public class LogoutController {

@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null){    
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
    }
    return "redirect:/login?logout";//You can redirect wherever you    want, but generally it's a good practice to show login screen again.
  }
 }
```

Tiles configuration general.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="common" template="/WEB-INF/layouts/classic.jsp">
<put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/layouts/footer.jsp" />
  </definition>

<definition name="index" extends="common">
<put-attribute name="title" value="JAVA BLOG AGGREGATOR" />
<put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp" />
<put-attribute name="current" value="index" />
  </definition>

  <definition name="users" extends="common">
<put-attribute name="title" value="users" />
<put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/users.jsp" />
<put-attribute name="current" value="users" />
  </definition>

  <definition name="user-details" extends="common">
<put-attribute name="title" value="user-details" />
<put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/user-details.jsp" />
<put-attribute name="current" value="users" />
 </definition>

 <definition name="user-register" extends="common">
<put-attribute name="title" value="user-register" />
<put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/user-register.jsp" />
<put-attribute name="current" value="register" />
 </definition>


 <definition name="login" extends="common">
<put-attribute name="title" value="login" />
<put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp" />
<put-attribute name="current" value="login" />
 </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Comment: Why do you even have a controller for `/logout`? Spring Security already handles all of that (and more). When using CSFR you need to POST to the logout URL and not GET (like a regular link). As explained http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-form

Comment: I have deleted the LogoutController.java file and Still having same issue with logout. Still getting same error message.(

    HTTP ERROR 404

    Problem accessing /logout. Reason:

    Not Found

)..btw I am not very clear about what I need to do when you said "When using CSFR you need to POST to the logout URL and not GET (like a regular link)" can you explain if I need to do anything specific to resolve my issue..I am also using Apache tiles..Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you actually READ my comment, and the link provided in that comment.

Comment: Yes Deinum. I read the comments and the link in the article too..I am having challenges to follow what I really need to do here.

Comment: A simple link won't work... You need to use a form and post (as explained with code in the reference guide).

Comment: Which link are we talking about. Please give me more details

Comment: Your question is about logout, so naturally the logout link.